# How do I stop Avro from autoboxing primitive types?

Tags: java, avro, autoboxing

When I put this into my avro schema:

```
{ "name": "the_id", "type": "int" },
```

And then I:

```
mvn generate-sources
```

A class file is generated that contains the following:

```
private int the_id;
/**
* All-args constructor.
*/
public TheObject(java.lang.Integer the_id, ...

public java.lang.Integer getTheId() {
 return the_id;
}
```

"the_id" is declared as an int and then boxed into an Integer in the constructor, and the getter(and the setter although I haven't included that in the code example).

Applying the "autoboxing is bad for performance" principle I would like to stop this from happening.
I've checked the docs and scoured the forums and haven't found anything useful: 
(This [Avro mail archive post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/avro-dev/201101.mbox/%3C1635C9724D9733459862AB57E8AE1D8503AE8BC0@ex2k.bankofamerica.com%3E) suggests that autoboxing is "free" in modern JVMs, but this [post from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html) disagrees).
Meanwhile [this post](http://apache-avro.679487.n3.nabble.com/Generate-java-code-with-getters-returning-primitives-instead-of-wrapper-classes-td4032580.html) to the Avro mail archive has gone unanswered.

Does anyone know of a way to stop Avro from autoboxing?